# change the color of a single QListView index upon double clicking it

Tags: qt, textcolor, qlistview

First off, I'm a Qt newbie:
I would like to change a QListView entry's text color upon double clicking it but I'm not exactly sure how to go about it. I'm able to get the index of the item double clicked:

```
void Widget::on_HostList_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText(QString::number(index.row()));
    msgBox.exec();
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
model->setData(vIndex, QBrush(Qt::red), Qt::ForegroundRole);
```

This is what I've found

Comment: I tried to use it with model being of type `QAbstractItemModel*` but I get `error: no matching function for call to 'QAbstractItemModel::setData(int&, QBrush, Qt::ItemDataRole)'
         model->setData(row, QBrush(Qt::red), Qt::ForegroundRole);`

Comment: @cerr change `model->setData(row, QBrush(Qt::red), Qt::ForegroundRole);` to `model->setData(index, QBrush(Qt::red), Qt::ForegroundRole);`. You have to pass the index not the row.

Comment: @eyllanesc I've tried this with no success, the color doesn't change: `void Widget::on_HostList_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QAbstractItemModel *model = ui->HostList->model();
    model->setData(index,QBrush(Qt::red), Qt::ForegroundRole);
}`

Comment: @cerr I think your project is small, you could share your project through github, drive or similar.

Comment: @eyllanesc correct, I've shared my project on Google Drive, please see: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-Kt3raDsPs9blJqTmprUTFyaVU?usp=sharing